# How to insert checkbox value into database in html?

Tags: html, checkbox

until now all the answers i have checked was helping people that use php.
i'm working on HTML for school project and i need to ensert terms of service checkbox to the database and JS check.
any help please.

Answer (score 2):

You need some post-processing script. You cannot insert data into database directly from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

HTML and JavaScript are front-end languages, meaning they are used to display some kind of data to users.
These languages cannot be used to alter databases, so you will have to use a back-end language (like PHP).